# QImage::scaleHeight transformation mode returning NULL image

Tags: c++, qt, scaling, qtgui, qimage

I'm trying to resize the image size to 120X240.

```
image = image.scaledToHeight(120);
image = image.scaledToWidth(240);
```

For some images which have dimension 837x630 ,getting error as,

```
QImage::scaleHeight: Image is a null image
QImage::scaleWidth: Image is a null image
```

Some images scalling properly which having nearly same dimensions(837X 642)
What is the reason for those errors..Some images are scaling properly and some not ..why?

Comment: Can we see how you initialize the `image`?

Comment: QString lPath =(QString) GPathAlphabets.c_str();
    lPath.append("/").append(pAlphabetFilePath);
    QImage  image(lPath);

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor for `QImage` is somehow constructing a *null image*. You should handle the case where this happens with [`QImage::isNull`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#isNull):

```
if (image.isNull())
    // throw error
```

Also you should do:

```
image = QImage(image.scaled(240, 120));
```

instead.

Comment: If given height/width is zero or negative, only at that time it has to return NULL image. But in my case image having valid height and width..

Comment: @user3167959, what I'm saying is that `image` is already a null image at the moment of the function call to scale it.